# Localized Default-568h@2x.png

Tags: xcode, default.png, localized

In one of my apps, I've created localized Default.png. Works great !

But, in Xcode 4.5.2 (same problem existed in the previous version of the software, I remember), I have a warning : "Retina 4 Support - Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image"...

If I set a launch image in my Targets summary, the warning disappeared, but localization does not work at all : whatever the language of the device go, the same launch screen is shown...

Is it a way I'm missing to pass away this warning without add specific iPhone5 home screen in App Targets ?
(Again, the splash screen is present (localized) and works both in simulator and device.)

Thanks all for your answers.

Nico3D